# SPFX Change the position of a ListView Command Set button in the command bar

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, spfx

I created a custom SPFX ListView Command Set button in the command bar which works fine. My only concern is that I don't control his order of appearance in the command bar. My goal is to be able to place it further left or further right as I desire. Also, is there anyway to move or hide the microsoft build-in button(Open, Share, Flow, and so on...)?

[See Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECEKm.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This is known case, check [#4121](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/4121) and [I suggest you](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329220-sharepoint-dev-platform/suggestions/37914715-use-sequence-parameter-to-sort-listview-command-se).

To hide build-in command, you could inject custom CSS, check [this github demo](https://github.com/hugoabernier/react-application-injectcss).